# How do I use the Case Expression in conjunction with a where clause to divide one filed by another?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to use case expression with a select query and a where clause and alias result as 'CaseOnOrder'.
Ideally when salunitmsr. = w then divide by U_SpecWgt as Case on order, when salunitmsr. = E than CaseOnOrder = OnOrder

I have two values that can only equal E or W, When the value is 'W' I would like the field OnOrder to divide by the U_SpecWgt field.  When the Value is 'E' than the OnOrder qty will not need to be changed.  The two select queries are below.  I am not sure how to incorporate the case logic to divide when W is present, and keep the value the same when 'E' is present.

```
SELECT  [ItemCode]
      ,[ItemName]
      ,[FrgnName]
      ,[ItmsGrpCod]
      ,[OnOrder]
      ,[U_SpecWgt]
  FROM [xxxxx].[xxxxx].[xxxxx]
  where 
  SalUnitMsr = 'e'
  AND SellItem = 'Y'
  and OnOrder > 0

  SELECT  [ItemCode]
      ,[ItemName]
      ,[FrgnName]
      ,[ItmsGrpCod]
      ,[OnOrder]
      ,[U_SpecWgt]
  FROM [xxxxx].[xxxxx].[xxxxx]
  where 
  SalUnitMsr = 'w'
  AND SellItem = 'Y'
  and OnOrder > 0
```

The query will include an aliased column that divides OnOrder by U_SpecWGT when salunitmsr = W, as cases on order, when E OnOrder = Cases on order.

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT 
   [ItemCode],
   [ItemName],
   [FrgnName],
   [ItmsGrpCod],
   CASE WHEN SalUnitMsr = 'W' THEN OnOrder/U_SpecWgt 
        WHEN SalUnitMsr = 'E' THEN OnOrder
   END AS [CasesOnOrder],
   [U_SpecWgt]
  FROM [xxxxx].[xxxxx].[xxxxx]
  where  SalUnitMsr IN ('W','E') AND SellItem = 'Y' and OnOrder > 0
```

Comment: Thank you, I am running the query as shown, however I think I need to utilize an isumeric function, as I am receiving the error below. Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Clarification of Table Structure Itemcode, ItemName, FrgnName, SalUnitMSR (Nvarchar) ItmsGrpCod (smallint), U_SpecWGT (int)

Comment: @Thomas What exactly is the formula when `SalUnitMsr = 'W'`

Comment: @Thomas -- what type is OnOrder?

Comment: OnOrder is currently not a field on the table, I do not wish to add it.  I only want to see it as an aliased column if that makes sense.

Comment: @Thomas -- if it is not a column in the table when what do I divide by U_SpecWgt when Salunitmsr = 'W'?

Comment: I am sorry OnOrder would be the field that U_SpecWGT is being divided by and that is on the table.  The aliased field populated by the case expression would be cases on order. Does that help?

Comment: @Thomas -- yes.  so what is the data type of OnOrder?

Comment: my apologies for not including that above.  OnOrder is data type numeric(19,6)